# How do I remove textExt from my textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-textext

I am using textext with my textarea:

http://textextjs.com/manual/index.html

It works and setting it up is simple but how do I destroy the textext i.e I want my plain textarea back on blur event

Answer (score 1):

If you used a plugin to manipulate a certain DOM element, one could simply remove that element, save its contents in a temporary variable and simply create that element again.

```
$("#element").someCoolPlugin(...);
```

So now the `someCoolPlugin()` plugin has done some manipulation to that element (added glitter or autocomplete or something) and we want to revert it back to its original form.  For this example, as in your question we'll use a textarea.

```
var newElement = $('<textarea id="element">' + $("#element").val() + '</textarea>');
```

If you want to preserve other parameters I'm sure you can see that it is easy to accomplish.

---

I glanced through that plugin and didn't see a `remove()` method, but you should take a closer look and see if maybe the plugin itself provides some sort of reset functionality... It would only be polite of the maker of the plugin to provide an option to undo his [awesome trickery](http://www.zurb.com/playground/jquery-raptorize) :)

Comment: The value of the tags are not held in the textarea, the textarea remains empty after each carriage-return. It stores the data in a JSON encoded string in a hidden input next to the textarea.

Comment: well there you go - thanks @mih!  @Tim, You can simply extract the value from the hidden input.

Comment: You should json_decode the value and use **variable.join(', ');** on it so you will have the same result as if you would have typed the labels in yourself (and separated them with comas).